# print system name in C?

Tags: c, linux, operating-system

Supposed I have myname.c is compiled to get executable file myname.
 And I want to print OS name after command:

$myname --system-name

output: Linux

Here is what I have so far

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/utsname.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

   struct utsname buffer;
   char str[70];
   scanf("%[^\n]",str);

   if (uname(&buffer) == system-name){

        printf(
            "%s",
            (&buffer)->sysname,
        );

   }
```

Comment: What's the question? What's this condition `if (uname(&buffer) == system-name){` supposed to do? You are reading `str` but is not used anywhere. What's the purpose of it?

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding, I try to use uanme() function to get some information about the system, and I want to create the multiple condition that will printf after the user enter specific name(ex: $myname --system name), it will output the current system Linux.

Comment: Do you mean `if (strcmp(str, "system-name") == 0)` to see if the user typed `system-name`?

Comment: Yes. That is what I mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this should work (your buffer is not a pointer and your if statement is not sensical, and you should also return something from main in that declaration method):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/utsname.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  struct utsname uts;
  if(uname(&uts) !=0 ) {
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }
  printf("%s\n",uts.sysname);
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

On linux to have some info's you can use the following:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<sys/utsname.h>

int main(void){
    struct utsname detect;

    uname(&detect);

    printf("System name - %s \n", detect.sysname);
    printf("Nodename    - %s \n", detect.nodename);
    printf("Release     - %s \n", detect.release);
    printf("Version     - %s \n", detect.version);
    printf("Machine     - %s \n", detect.machine);
    printf("Domain name - %s \n", detect.__domainname);

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
System name - Linux 
Nodename    - michi 
Release     - 3.19.0-32-generic 
Version     - #37~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Oct 22 09:41:40 UTC 2015 
Machine     - x86_64 
Domain name - (none)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're looking for:

```
if (strcmp(str, "system-name") == 0){
    printf("%s\n", buffer.sysname);
}
```

`strcmp()` is the C function for comparing strings, so this will check whether the user entered `system-name`.

When you have a structure, you can use `.` to access an element of it, you don't need to take its address and use indirection. You also had an extra comma at the end of your `printf()` argument list.